# Convert fraction to decimal number

Tags: java, floating-point, integer

i'm doing some exercises in my Java book. I'm very new to programming. Therefore, notice (in the code) that i'm still on Chapter one. Now I already did everything, I just want a confirmation if this is legitimate so I can feel free to move on next.

If not, I would sincerely appreciate to **not** do my code for me; I want advice.

**Here's the question written in the book**,
*"Write an application that prompts/reads the numerator and denominator of a fraction as integers, then prints the decimal equivalent of the fraction."*

I'll illustrate this sentence with my code:

**I did a revision here. Is this one OK?..**

```
import java.util.*;
public class ExerciseEleven {
public static void main (String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

    double fraction;
    int fractionValue;
    int decimal;
    double value;

    System.out.println("Enter Numerator: ");
    int numerator = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Denominator: ");
    int denominator = sc.nextInt();

    fraction = (double) numerator / denominator;
    fractionValue = (int) (fraction * 10);
    decimal = fractionValue % 10;
    value = decimal * 0.1;


    System.out.println(value);
}
}
```

It compiles and works fine. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't do what task says it should. You read doubles instead of integers, and the decimal equivalent is not what you print out. Decimal equivalent for 1/2 is 0.5. And you print 5.

Also, you can pay attention to your code style: variable names are usually written in lowerCamelCase, like that : `simpleVariable`.

**Update**

now it prints what you need. However you do it not in the very right way and your indentation can still be improved.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.                                               if statements, math classes etc has not yet been covered as i'm still in Chap 1. If you have any idea how to improve it, please hand some advice :)

Answer (score 3):

<s>It's fine</s> *(I didn't read the assignment very well, did I? Kudos to [Vladimir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538872/is-this-java-program-legitimate-newbie/4538917#4538917).)* ...but some comments:

- Usually you want to indent methods within the class.
- Standard practice is to use initial caps (`Numerator`) only for types (e.g., classes, interfaces, enums). Variable, field, and method names should start with a lower-case letter. Now, you're free to ignore standard practice, but if you do people will have a *lot* of trouble reading your code. :-)
- For rounding, you probably want to look at [`Math.round`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)) rather than truncating with a cast. But the assignment didn't say anything about rounding.
- You might want to handle the case where `denominator` is zero.

So keeping those in mind:

```
import java.util.*;

public class ExcerciseEleven  {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Numerator: ");
        int numerator = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Denominator: ");
        int denominator = sc.nextInt();
        if (denominator == 0) {
            System.out.println("Can't divide by zero");
        }
        else {
            double fraction = (double)numerator / denominator;
            System.out.println(fraction);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have forgot about interfaces and enumerations

Comment: Math.round, if statements etc has not yet been covered in chapter one. Thanks for the tips about the standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I am doing some thinking about this and I have noticed something interesting after looking at this source and here is the Algorithm that I plan on implementing

1. First I will convert the number from the Metric using the
   Javax.Measure family of functions and I will get a number like
   0.3750
2. Then I will divide the number by ONE_SIXTEENTH which = 0.0625
   `ONE_SIXTEENTH = 0.0625` 
   The answer 0.3750 / ONE_SIXTEENTH = 6;
3. So now I know there are 6 sixteenths of the inch
4. Next I check to see if 6 is divisible by 4, 6/4 = 1.5 ie not a whole number so the fraction is still regarded as 6/16th of an inch for now
5. Next I check to see if 6 is divisible by 2, 6/2 = 3
   This is a whole number so we will use it to reconstitute the fraction
6. So now that we have divided 6 by 2 and gotten 3 the 16 needs to be divided by 2 and we end up with 8 so 6/16th of an inch becomes 3/8th of an inch.

PS Has anyone noticed that this is similar to a fizz bang program?

### ____________________________________________

[Here is the chart which helped me get my head around this](https://www.plumbingsupply.com/metric.html)

[image: This is how I worked out how I was going to do this]
My workings

Answer (score 0):

There are three important parts of division operation :

1. Sign of the result.
2. Integral part
3. Decimal part

Also, there are few corner cases where you need to deal with the fact that `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` when compared in *absolute* form.

For example : `-2147483648/-1` can't yield `2147483648` when divided in the form of integer types. The reason is simple. The type of the resulting type will be integer type, and the maximum positive value that a integer type variable can hold is `+2147483647`

To mitigate that scenario, we should at first convert both the numerator and denominator into their long positive form. That gives us the **integral** part of the answer.

The XOR of two numbers will have the sign bit as `1` only in case they have opposite signs. That solves the first part (**sign** of result) of the problem.

For **decimal** part, we can employ the general division rule i.e. multiply the remainder with `10` and try dividing again and repeat. Keep record of the remainder we have already come across to prevent the loop from going into unbounded iterations.

```
public String fractionToDecimal(int A, int B) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((A^B) < 0 ? "-" : "");
    long a = Math.abs((long)A);
    long b = Math.abs((long)B);
    sb.append(Long.toString(a/b));

    long rem = a % b; 
    sb.append((rem != 0) ? "." : "");
    Map<Long, Integer> remainderMap = new HashMap<>();
    int pos = 0;
    while (rem != 0){
        sb.append(Long.toString((rem*10)/b));
        remainderMap.put(rem, pos++);
        rem = (rem*10) % b;
        if (remainderMap.containsKey(rem)){
            String currNum[] = sb.toString().split("\\.");
            return currNum[0] + "." + currNum[1].substring(0, remainderMap.get(rem)) + 
                        "(" + currNum[1].substring(remainderMap.get(rem)) + ")";   
        }
    }
    if (sb.toString().equals("-0")) return "0"; 
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Sample output :

- `2/3` gives `0.(6)`
- `-2147483648/-1` gives `2147483648`